# I am attempting to create a method which generates a true or false return value for a Fibonacci detection method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am attempting to create a method which generates a true or false return value when a number is given as its argument to detect if the number is a Fibonacci sequence, although I have never encountered a number like so:

2.073668380220713e+21 .

Forgive my ignorance but is there a way to deal with this type of value in ruby to make it work in the method below?

```
def is_fibonacci?(num)
  high_square = Math.sqrt((5 * num) * num + 4)

  low_square = Math.sqrt((5 * num) * num - 4)

  # If high_square or low_square are perfect squares, return true, else false.
  high_square == high_square.round || low_square == low_square.round ? true : false
end

puts is_fibonacci?(927372692193078999171) # Trying to return false, but returns true. The sqrt of this number is 2.073668380220713e+21. 
puts is_fibonacci?(987) # Returns true as expected.
```

Comment: That's just a very large number expressed in scientific notation. Hmm, but it's the sqrt of a smaller number? You may be running into integer overflow.

Comment: @Satya: It is the sqrt of a larger number. The problem is just lack of precision.

Comment: @Satya: There is no integer overflow in Ruby. This is, however, not an `Integer`, it is a `Float`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe because it's such a large number it's being displayed as scientific notation by Ruby and not able to work in your is_fibonacci? method with the basic Math library.

You might want to look into using the BigMath library for Ruby http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigMath.html

**Edit** As  Niel pointed out, it's a Ruby float and has therefore lost precision. Big Math should still do the trick for you.

Comment: It is not only being *displayed* in scientific notation, but is a Ruby `Float`, therefore has lost precision where the OP needs it. I think your suggestion is sound, although you may want to expand on it with an example.